# CSS Bug on Crypto Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, per-site-meta

I'd like to report a bug concerning *at least* [crypto.meta.se](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/) for which it appears that the CSS has "died". I've got this confirmed from two other users.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit [Crypto Meta SE](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/)
2. Observe missing page layout

Expected result:
A proper page layout as is used on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [InfoSec Meta SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Buggy View:

> [image: The buggy view]

Comment: This was posted on MSE because a) I didn't want to post it on the broken site and b) it _may_ affect other network sites as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a production build failure earlier (build agent ran out of memory) that we thought didn't affect actual deployment... but apparently did. Re-ran the build and all the assets are back where they belong, it looks like. Thanks for the report!